# Granting per-node-type permissions in hook_node_type_insert()

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks, users

I use the [Override Node Options](http://drupal.org/project/override_node_options) module to specify granular permissions for publishing, leaving Revision log entries, etc. for each node type.

I almost always grant the same set of permissions to a certain role for every node type, so I thought I'd have Drupal automatically assign them on node type creation:

```
function MYMODULE_node_type_insert($info) {
    if(module_exists('override_node_options')) {
        user_role_grant_permissions(4, array(
            'override ' . $info->type . ' published option',
            'enter ' . $info->type . ' revision log entry'
        ));
        $role = user_role_load(4);
        drupal_set_message(t('The @role role has been given permission to publish, unpublish, and enter revision logs on @nodetype nodes.', array('@role' => $role->name, '@nodetype' => $info->type)));
    }
}
```

But when I do so, I get errors:

> *Notice: Undefined index: override NODETYPE published option in user_role_grant_permissions() (line 3152 of /htdocs/modules/user/user.module).*
>
> *PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'module' cannot be null: UPDATE {role_permission} SET module=:db_update_placeholder_0 WHERE ( (rid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (permission = :db_condition_placeholder_1) ); Array ( [:db_update_placeholder_0] => [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 4 [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => override NODETYPE published option ) in user_role_grant_permissions() (line 3154 of /htdocs/modules/user/user.module).*

As it happens, `node_type_get_types()` ( which is called by `node_permissions_get_configured_types()`) does not return the node type I'm in the middle of creating, even though [the documentation says](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_type_get_types/7) "This list can include types that are queued for addition or deletion."

So now I'm flummoxed. How can I set a per-node-type permission automatically when that node type is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, my bet is that the new node type isn't getting added to the cached list of types that `node_type_get_types()` returns. At the very end of `node_type_save()`, it calls `node_type_cache_reset()`, but that's probably running too late for your code.

So try putting a call to `node_type_cache_reset()` at the top of your function, and hopefully that will do the trick.